# ruby hash undefined method `key' for main:Object (NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, hash

I am learning ruby, had below error in Ruby

> > myfile1.rb:13:in 'block in ': undefined method 'key' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
> >       from myfile1.rb:13:in 'keep_if'
> >       from myfile1.rb:13:in ''

Code written is as below:

```
hackerrank = Hash.new
hackerrank.keep_if { |key, value| key is_a? Integer }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering my own question as per `share your knowledge` rules on SO)

The issue is in 2nd line/ below code:

```
hackerrank.keep_if { |key, value| key is_a? Integer }
```

`is_a?` method should be called on `key`, so correct usage is `key.is_a?`, so the fix is as below:

```
hackerrank.keep_if { |key, value| key.is_a? Integer }
```

Note that "." (dot) is added after `key` as in `key.` in the above.

Comment: Note that the method is called [`is_a?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) including the question mark. Method names in Ruby can end with `?`, `!`, and `=`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ also there is a convention to prepend unused variables with underscore to tell both ruby parser and editor syntax highlighting engine that the variable is not used: `|key, value| ...` → `|key, _value| ...` or even `|key, _| ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at this line of code:

`hackerrank.keep_if { |key, value| key is_a? Integer }`

The reason why `key` is treated as method here is because omission of parentheses is allowed when calling a method in Ruby.

So the code above is actually interpreted as  below:

`hackerrank.keep_if { |key, value| key( is_a?( Integer) ) }`

hence the error message about undefined method 'key':

> myfile1.rb:13:in 'block in ': undefined method 'key' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Put "." behind `key` to imply the object that is calling for the method `is_a?`. Like this:

```
hackerrank.keep_if { |key, value| key.is_a? Integer }
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. The answer with comments is already written below, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55988335/984471, can your how-it-is-interpreted be a comment to it?